# What is the pdf and cdf of $Y := XD +(1-X)P$ where $X \sim Ber(p)$, $D\sim Exp(\lambda_d)$,$P\sim Exp(\lambda_p)$?

Tags: probability-distributions

What is the pdf and cdf of $Y := XD +(1-X)P$ where $X \sim Ber(p)$, $D\sim Exp(\lambda_d)$,$P\sim Exp(\lambda_p)$? All variables are independet.

Thanks for the hint.
By the Hint below:

$$f_Y(y)=f_Y(y)\biggr\vert_{X=1}\Pr(X=1)+f_Y(y)\biggr\vert_{X=0}\Pr(X=0)
 = f_D(y)p + f_P(y)(1-p) = \lambda_d e^{-\lambda_d y}p + (1-p)\lambda_p e^{-\lambda_p y} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is called a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f_Y(y)=f_Y(y)\biggr\vert_{X=1}\Pr(X=1)+f_Y(y)\biggr\vert_{X=0}\Pr(X=0)$$